# Groovy find the last iteration inside a cloure?

Tags: groovy, closures, iteration

In groovy how to find the last iteration inside the closure.

```
def closure = { it->
   //here I need to print last line only
}

new File (file).eachLine{ closure(it)}
```

Need to find inside the `closure` iteration.

Update 1:

Instead of reading a file, In Common How can i find the last iteration inside the closure ?

```
def closure = { it->
   //Find last iteration here
}
```

Comment: Why not `new File (file).readLines[-1]`?

Comment: @Opal Thanks for response. but i want to know inside the closure iteration.

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U, what is your use case? Because, it is not clear why it should be done in closure only? The more context would help to suggest better solution.

Comment: @Rao Just i am trying do independently inside the closure.bcoz if i did , It would optimize my code.  Actually the need is not only for reading file. Sure it will work for other purposes. :)

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U the above comment does not answer the requested info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need `eachWithIndex`:

```
def f = new File('TODO')
def lines = f.readLines().size()

def c = { l, i ->
    if(i == lines - 1) {
        println "last: $i $l"
    }
}

f.eachWithIndex(c)
```

Of course in case of big files you need to count lines [efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277880/how-can-i-get-the-count-of-line-in-a-file-in-an-efficient-way).

Comment: Is there any simple way instead of this?

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually you did this with `f.readLines().size()`. but this file `readLine` which i put is for example. I want to check the final iteration inside the closure function only not from the source as you approach.

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U, sorry I don't understand. If you want to check final iteration use for loop. It's not possible with `eachLine` closure.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion bro.

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U, if you find it useful, it is appreciated an up vote & consider accepting it as answered. If it does not answer your problem, question should clarify requested info by answerer instead of just thanks. You must understand that some one spent his precious time on your issue.